# totally split primes in a number field

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, ramification

I have to show: For any number field $K$, there are infinitely many prime numbers $p \in \mathbb{N}$, that are totally split in $K$.

I think have already shown (with some hints my professor gave) that for any prime $p$ coprime to $ [K:\mathbb{Q}] $that $ \mathcal{O}_K/p\mathcal{O}_K \cong \mathbb{F}_p $ (for the integral closure $\mathcal{O}_K$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $K$).

So I have to show, that there are prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}_1, \dots ,\mathfrak{p}_{[K:\mathbb{Q}]} $ with $(p)=\mathfrak{p}_1...\mathfrak{p}_{[K:\mathbb{Q}]}$

But from here on I don't really know what to do.

Another hint was to use this fact: For any $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x] \setminus \mathbb{Z}$ there are infinitely many primes $p$ with $p \mid f(n)$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

also it should be useful to reduce the problem to a galois field

If anybody has an idea, I'd be glad to hear it

Thank you!

Comment: Only finitely many primes ramify...

Comment: Yeah, only primes that divide the discriminant ramify

Comment: argh yes, what I meant was $(p)=\mathfrak{p}_1...\mathfrak{p}_{[K:\mathbb{Q}]$

Comment: The word you're looking for is "split".

Comment: I've corrected "ramified" to "split", but I'll leave it to you to edit your post to correct the mathematical content: I don't want to change the meaning of what you write since I can't actually be sure precisely what your problem is.

Comment: Dear @user152951, What do you mean by $\mathscr{O}_K\simeq\mathbf{F}_p$? This doesn't make sense. The LHS is a domain of characteristic zero and the RHS is a field of characteristic $p$.

Comment: I'm so sorry, don't know what I was thinking
hopefully I#ve corrected all mistakes

Comment: @Keenan Kidwell I meant $ \mathcal{O} _K / p \mathcal{O} _K \cong \mathbb{F}_p$